# Bootstrap modal not appearing, despite all files included and HTML appearing correct

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

This may appear duplicate, but all other answers I've seen relate to incorrect inclusion of scripts or incorrect assignment of `data-*` values.

I have a very simple bootstrap modal (version 3.3.6 updated this morning) which I cannot for the life of me get to appear!
Working in MVC5, I have a standard view which I wanted a bootstrap modal to appear on a button within a datatable. To ruleout datatables itself, I've taken this button out and just stuck it on the page.

The button looks like this:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary edit-modal" data-target="#modal-container" data-trigger="modal">Edit</a>
```

I'm including jQuery v2.1.4 (min) and bootstrap 3.3.6 (min) in that order:

[image]

I've taken a stock modal HTML snippet from the Bootstrap example site and set it up with minor changes:

```
<div id="modal-container" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="model-close-btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Edit</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(I've taken both of those HTML snippets from the output HTML not the `.cshtml` in case they have been fiddled with by MVC / JS on the way out)

I can't see anything wrong with this config, but no matter what I've tried, I can't get the modal to show.

There are no console errors either `onload` or `onclick` and the page renders with the modal hidden (so I assume BS is performing something!)

All other usages of jQuery & Bootstrap, styling and code wise work, with this one exception.

**Things I've tried:**

- Updating BS and jQuery
- Moving the modal html around (just before body end, just after body start, randomly in the middle!)
- Removing the `data-*` tags and binding a click even to the button
- Changing the id of the modal

I'm now out of ideas, and with no errors there isn't a lot more I can think to debug.

Any thoughts or even vague areas to investigate with be hugely helpful.

Comment: Can you a make a fiddle which shows your issues ?

Comment: Jquery modal never worked this way for me , always I had to do modal.show() on button click from javaScript.

Comment: @sapy I did think of this, tried a click handle but no joy either

Comment: `$('#buttonId').click(function(){$('#myModal').modal('show')})` **will work** .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you change the anchor tag by replacing **data-trigger="modal"** to **[data-toggle="modal"](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp)**

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary edit-modal" data-target="#modal-container" data-toggle="modal">Edit</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary edit-modal" data-target="#modal-container" data-toggle="modal">Edit</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try href="javascript:void(0)" may be it think you need to do remote loading or replace the  tag with button

Comment: I forgot to add that the a href was in place of the button I initially replaced in case that was the problem